# Combining group by and join into one query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I know that similar questions were asked in the past and I browsed through them but none of the answers seem to work on my specific problem. Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    a.productid,
    a.SUM(amount),
    b.name
FROM
    sales a
JOIN 
    products b ON b.Id = a.productid
GROUP BY 
    a.productid
```

2 tables: sales, products. Sales contains the following columns: Id, amount, price, productid. Products contains: Id, name.

For some reason my query doesn't work. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: All attributes which are not in an aggregate function, have to be in the `group by`. So you need to add `b.name` to the `group by`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
a.productid,
SUM(amount),
b.name
FROM
sales a
JOIN products b ON b.Id = a.productid
GROUP BY a.productid, b.name
```

Columns(`a.productid`, `b.name`) which are not in the aggregate function needs to be added in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I hadn't noticed before, but I suspect `a.SUM(amount)` will throw an error too; this should be plain `SUM(a.amount)`

Comment: @HoneyBadger:- Yes you are correct. updated my answer. Nice pick!